# Solving a system of trig equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

[image]

My book somehow got from those top two equations in the picture and solved for v'2(t) + v'1(t). I don't see how they did this? Can anyone see the trick for this type of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the top equation by $\sin{t}$ and the bottom equation by $\cos{t}$.  Add.

Comment: Oh my gosh! I can't believe I didnt see that...